# Why would fgets() allocate over 1 million bytes

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, valgrind, fgets

Ok. So I have simply run into some strange behaviour when using fgets in a very simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char line[80];
    fgets(line, 80, file);
    printf("%s", line);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The file being opened contains a single line and is only 25 bytes in size. When rerunning the executable through valgrind it declares that over 1 million bytes are allocated with only 3 allocs (coupled with 3 frees).

I was just wondering why this might be.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I doubt `fgets` itself allocate anything. But the run-time system might, as well as space for buffers for the file and `stdout`. And as it seems like all allocations are matched with freeing the memory, there's no leak so really no problem. As for what, where and for why the allocations happen, if you're on e.g. Linux then all parts of the chain is open-source with the source available to read to find out what's happening. Or you can step through the code in a debugger, including stepping into the library calls.

Comment: I have narrowed down the line where the huge amounts of memory are being allocated to the fgets() line though

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm compiling and running on a linux server my university hosts, it runs Debian 4.9.130-2

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: As other's have mentioned, it could be a library implementation, like that of `fgets` or even `printf`, and if you're doing it on a uni computer, there's other unknowns ... can you post the valgrind output so we can analyze??

Comment: @txtechhelp
`==11699== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info

==11699== Command: ./a.out

==11699== 

THIS IS A ONE LINE FILE

==11699== 

==11699== HEAP SUMMARY:

==11699==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==11699==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,050,152 bytes allocated

==11699== 

==11699== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

==11699== 

==11699== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==11699== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

Comment: If you want to see where the memory is being allocated, try Massif, the memory profiler.